# Was the Airbus A300/A310 ever supplied with a yoke and not a sidestick?

Tags: cockpit, airbus, sidestick, airbus-a310, airbus-a300

In the Air Crash Investigation episode "Kid In The Cockpit," which details the crash of [Aeroflot Flight 593](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroflot_Flight_593), the video shows the plane had a yoke not a sidestick

I was under the impression all Airbus models, even the earlier ones, used a sidestick.

Can anybody clarify this for me?

Comment: you sir, have a sharp eye for detail! +1 :)

Comment: Perhaps we should rename the question include A300/A310 to emphasize the similarity between the types and make it past tense.

Answer (score 32):

The sidestick was a design that came about along with the new [fly-by-wire technology of the A320](http://www.airbus.com/innovation/proven-concepts/in-design/fly-by-wire/) in the [late 1980's](http://www.airbus.com/company/history/the-narrative/fly-by-wire-1980-1987/). The physical leverage of a yoke was no longer needed for flight control cables. The older designs of the [A300 and A310 series planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus) from the 70's and 80's have [conventional yoke flight controls](https://www.google.com/search?q=AIRBUS%20a310%20cockpit).

I would not be surprised to see inaccuracies in TV reenactments, but the yoke did happen to be important in that particular case.

Comment: ... as was the autopilot with independently disconnectable axis (no longer possible on A320+) and lack of flight envelope protection (added on A320). Also MayDay/Air Crash Investigation is usually pretty accurate (does not necessarily extend to other similar documentaries).

Answer (score 0):

Great [video][1] of Azore Airelines A310 hand yoke flying over LPPD.

So yes, it did ship w/ a yoke. :)
[1]: